# Event reciever wont add users to visitors group on teamsite

Tags: user, feature-receiver

my code wont add nt authority users to group visitors in min team site why?

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {

        string usersAll = "NT AUTHORITY\authenticated users";
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate
        {
            using (SPSite spSite = SPContext.Current.Web.Site)
            {
                using (SPWeb spWeb = spSite.OpenWeb())
                {
                    try
                    {

                        spWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                        SPUser allusers = spWeb.EnsureUser(usersAll);
                        if (allusers != null)
                        {
                            SPGroup spGroup = spWeb.AssociatedVisitorGroup;
                            if (spGroup != null)
                            {
                                spGroup.AddUser(allusers);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {

                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        spWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                    }
                }
            }


        });
    }
```

Comment: i am not sure if its required but you can try adding `spGroup.update();` right after you add users.

Comment: Try to use NT AUTHORITY\\authenticated users (double \\).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
    string usersAll = "NT AUTHORITY\\authenticated users";
    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate
    {
        using (SPSite spSite = SPContext.Current.Web.Site)
        {
            using (SPWeb spWeb = spSite.OpenWeb())
            {
                try
                {
                    spWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    SPUser allusers = spWeb.EnsureUser(usersAll);
                    if (allusers != null)
                    {
                        SPGroup spGroup = spWeb.AssociatedVisitorGroup;
                        if (spGroup != null)
                        {
                            spGroup.AddUser(allusers);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
                finally
                {
                    spWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

A general suggestion, use

```
SPSite spSite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url)
```

instead of

```
SPSite spSite = SPContext.Current.Web.Site
```

So you will always have your SPSite and not something SharePoint created and managed for you.